# DataSet doesn't generate the updatecommand in new tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatecommand

When i try to insert a my database's table in my dataset, it doesn't generate the update command like had done with other tables.
It generates only insert and select commands

How can i do to generate it without write it manually?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved.
I had forgotten the primary key on my sql server table.